# IS there a rails war file equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning rails and have what seems to be a fairly easy question - except I don't know the answer. Going through the rails tutorials, I can get my apps to run on my dev machine. I can also copy the folders to a server and the app works there also. 
Question: Is there some way to deploy a war/jar type of file instead of the 'exploded' folder structure on the server?

Comment: What is the reason you want that? Do you use JRuby? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114616/can-a-rails-plugin-be-packaged-as-a-war-jar-file may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to deploy Rails applications is to use a tool like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), which will copy all the files across, and also provide you with a way of rolling back to a previous release in case of issues in production.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano is the way to deploy Rails applications.

It features SFTP-Transfer, supports various SCM like git, subversion, cvs and if you don't want to deploy via checkout you can let capistrano pack your application into an archive and deploy it to your production environment.

More about capistrano and its possibilities can be found in the [wiki](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki).